# RewriteRule for Alias

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

In my httpd.conf file I have setup of this way

```
DocumentRoot "/var/http/htdocs/STJ/Test"
Alias   /images                 "/var/http/htdocs/STJ/images"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(webapp/.*)$      http://examle.com:9983/$1 [P,L]
```

I would like to redirect Alias `/images`.
currently `Alias /images` is getting pulled form the same host, but i would like to pull images from different host. how i can redirect `Alias /images`

Comment: You use conflicting terminology. Do you want to _redirect_ it to another host, or read it (_pull_) from another directory, possibly another virtualhost on this machine? If redirection, to what host do you want to redirect it?

Comment: Note that without a proxy, redirecting them to another host will be visible to the client browser, unlike `Alias` which doesn't expose the real filesystem location.

Comment: I would like to pull from another host, directory are the same for the both host. so for example

Comment: I have www.example.com and the alias /images set on that box, but now i want to pull images from www.test.com so how i can redirect alials /images ?